# NSPredicate, search in a NSArray, inside a NSArray of NSDict

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`.

One of the keys of the `NSDictionary` contains a `NSArray` of strings.

Is there a way that I can use `NSPredicate` to find a specific strins in that Array of strings?

Thanks  :)

Also:  This work great, but not for sublevelArray

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" %K LIKE[cd] %@", sKey, sLookForString];
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are questions like this on SO, maybe not with that much sublevels, but, you could narrow your search, and modify the NSPredicate according to the other sublevel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace **LIKE** with **CONTAINS** in your format string. For example, given this array:

```
NSArray *dogs = @[@{@"name" : @"Fido",
                    @"toys" : @[@"Ball", @"Kong"]},
                  @{@"name" : @"Rover",
                    @"toys" : @[@"Ball", @"Rope"]},
                  @{@"name" : @"Spot",
                    @"toys" : @[@"Rope", @"Kong"]}];
```

...the following predicate can be used obtain a filtered array containing only the dictionaries where the value for the key **toy** is an array that contains the string **Kong**.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"toys", @"Kong"];
```

Answer (score 1):

On NSArray you can use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`, on NSDictionary use `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` and then for each value do either a `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` if it is an NSArray or you can use `evaluateWithObject:` using the predicate itself.

Comment: Just discover enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock.  Thanks for that!  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the array of dictionaries based on the array of strings, you can use -predicateWithBlock to filter the array, as shown in the code below:

```
- (NSArray *)filterArray:(NSArray *)array WithSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)evaluatedObject;
        NSArray *strings = [dictionary objectForKey:@"strings"];

        return [strings containsObject:searchString];
    }];

    return [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```